# getc is obsolete; use STDIN.getc instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rubygems

When running rake gems:install I see this message:

```
/opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:232: warning: getc is obsolete; use STDIN.getc instead
```

How do I resolve the issue?

Comment: What version of rubygems are you using? What does `gem -v` say?

Comment: And ruby version is: ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved by using sudo command i.e. sudo rake gems:install

Comment: so what is the root problem here?