# warning: getc is obsolete; use STDIN.getc instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, activesupport

I'm having a problem with my rails application.
When I type

> script/server

I get the following error:

```
/Users/admin/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/
lib/active_support/multibyte/unicode_database.rb:37: 
warning: getc is obsolete; use STDIN.getc instead
```

This causes the application to hang and not respond.

How can I resolve this?

(I'm using Rails 2.3.5, Gems 1.3.6, Ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i686-darwin9] on a Mac OS 10.5)

Comment: I was having a similar problem a few days ago when installing gems (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479201/getc-is-obsolete-use-stdin-getc-instead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated Ruby to

> ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-darwin9]

and the problem has not occurred since.